# Parsing a HTML response body using jquery in POSTMAN tests

Tags: jquery, html, postman

In **postman**, I have a collection in which I have 2 or more requests and I need to pass few parameters from first response to next one. 
The response is a HTML response and I m trying to get the value of parameter using jquery. 
`${'#id}.val()` and set it in environment variable

But this is not working in POSTMAN. It always returns a `null`. Is it possible to get the value like this in POSTMAN from html response. It works for JSON responses by using `JSON.parse` method

Answer (score 2):

The xml2Json() method might be of use here. So something like:

```
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("myEnvVariable", jsonData.id);
```

FYI, I'm using the POSTMAN Chrome Extension v5.0.1.